# Why does regex which works in tester not work in grok debugger?

Tags: regex, grok

I just started to use Logstash recently. I got a log message example:

```
\u0000Sp?\u0002\u0001A\u0000Sr?)\u0004£\u000Ex-opt-jms-destQ\u0001£\u0012x-opt-jms-msg-typeQ\u0005\u0000Ss?\u0000\u0000\u0000W\u0000\u0000\u0000\n¡0ID:06ecf56f-d295-4458-a981-d5badbb5b1a7:1:1:1-95@¡\u000Ftopic://MyTopic@@@@@@\u0083\u0000\u0000\u0001m^£\u0019\u0087\u0000Sw¡9This is a test message sent out at 2019-09-23 17:00:10 PM
```

I want to extract the message `This is a test message sent out at 2019-09-23 17:00:10 PM`. I tried the regex `This.*` and test it in the [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/378).

While when I use the same regex `(?<user_agent>[This.*])` in the grok debugger, it can only extract one character `s`.

```
{
  "user_agent": [
    [
      "s"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Why did you change the pattern inside the named capturing group? Use it as you had it: `(?<user_agent>This.*)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Solved. Should I close the question?